# Изменить заголовок окна при нажатии кнопки, находящейся на html странице.

Tags: javascript

Помогите, как правильно написать код изменения заголовка окна при нажатии кнопки, находящейся на html странице? Только начал изучать азы, а задание уже требуют!!!

Comment: `<input type="button" onclick="document.title = 'Заголовок';" valye="Set Title" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заголовок меняется с помощью:

```
document.title = 'Заголовок';
```

Для того чтобы этот код отработал при нажатии на кнопку, на это событие нужно установить свой обработчик с вышеуказанным кодом. Про события в JavaScript можно почитать [тут](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/events/intro).

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!!!